# CSS-Grid: minmax with fix min and max value

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a div-bar (red) with preview-items (orange) to choose from. Every item should have a min width of 5% of the parent width and a max-width of 10%.

[image]

The important thing here is, that the max-width of the preview-items should not be something like auto or 1fr, so that if some entity has only one preview item, it must not take all the available space.

On the other side, if I have more than 9 items, the first and the last item should touch each outer side. Like so:

[image]

From what I found so far, it seems that `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(5%, 10%));` should so the thing. But it does not. Instead, only the max-value is used.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/e34qpdrh/

Is this possible at all with just grid-attributes?

Comment: did you try 

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(5%, 1fr));`

Comment: or make it `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(5%, auto));` because in your way from 5 to 10 it will hit a point where there is no way to fit all the item in one line using 10% maybe that's why it's going to the new line?  try to make the container `max-width:600px` you will see the max 10% is working just fine. So it's working as it should to fit everything as request.

after changing the container to `max-width:600px` your code run and gave me the requested behaviour.